# Trying to divide two columns to get Percentage but gives me 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, format

**Objective:** I am trying to get the % difference between two columns but I think the problem lies in the type in the column.

**Situation:** I have two columns i must count `NON` `NULL` occurrences to find out how many times something happen in each month. And I want to get the % difference between these two columns.

**Query:**

```
SELECT *
    ,subquery3.[Email Logins Week2]/subquery3.[Email Logins Week1]
FROM    (
        SELECT  
             FORMAT(tbl3.Creation_Date, 'yyyyMM')       AS [Date Subscribed]
            ,CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.Emails IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS int)   AS [Email Logins Week1]
            ,CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.Emails IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS int)   AS [Email Logins Week2]
        FROM #tbl1 t1
        LEFT JOIN #tbl2 t2
            ON t1.Emails=t2.Emails
        INNER JOIN #tbl3 t3
            ON t1.Emails=t3.email
        GROUP BY FORMAT(t3.Creation_Date, 'yyyyMM')
        ) subquery3
```

This gives me something like this:

```
+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+
| Date Subscribed | Email Logins Week1 | Email Logins Week2 | (No column name) |
+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+
|          201801 |               6800 |               2000 |                0 |
|          201802 |               9000 |               3000 |                0 |
|          201803 |               7000 |               2500 |                0 |
|          201804 |               7200 |               2400 |                0 |
+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+
```

Instead of:

```
+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+
| Date Subscribed | Email Logins Week1 | Email Logins Week2 | (No column name) |
+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+
|          201801 |               6800 |               2000 |      0.294117647 |
|          201802 |               9000 |               3000 |      0.333333333 |
|          201803 |               7000 |               2500 |      0.357142857 |
|          201804 |               7200 |               2400 |      0.333333333 |
+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+
```

**Bonus:** Is there a way to get the difference % in my subquery so that I don't create a subquery????

Comment: Integer Math. An `int` divided by an `int` = an `int`. So `4/5=0`. Change `subquery3.[Email Logins Week1]` to `(subquery3.[Email Logins Week1]*1.0)`

Comment: You need to convert your counts to decimals (shortcut: multiply one of them by 1.0) - otherwise, dividing two integers returns another integer.  You can do this directly with your counts

Comment: Thank you guys! Have you read my Bonus Question at the end?

Comment: Try to cast one of your fields as a float, i.e.: `CAST(subquery3.[Email Logins Week2] AS FLOAT)`

If you don't want to create the subquery, you can just divide the case statements `CAST(CASE .... END AS FLOAT) / CASE ... END`

Comment: I've reopened, for the purposes of answering the "bonus".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should provide you with an answer to the "bonus". note my other comments in the below as well though:

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(8),t3.Creation_Date,112),6) AS [Date Subscribed], --FORMAT performs poorly, this'll be faster
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.Emails IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS [Email Logins Week1], --COUNT already returns an int
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.Emails IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS [Email Logins Week2], --I've also removed the ELSE NULL as a CASE expression that doesn't resolve returns NULL
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.Emails IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) / (COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.Emails IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.0) AS OtherColumn
FROM #tbl1 t1
     LEFT JOIN #tbl2 t2 ON t1.Emails = t2.Emails
     INNER JOIN #tbl3 t3 ON t1.Emails = t3.email
GROUP BY LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(8),t3.Creation_Date,112),6);
```